# Android: How to prevent developer options from resetting upon the next boot?

Tags: java, android, settings

This is my first post so bear with me. I'm a maintainer for the Paranoid Android ROM and very new to Java. Basically my devices require the "Disable HW overlays" option in "Settings>Developer options" to be permanently enabled in order to prevent screen flickering. The thing is it is normal AOSP behaviour for some "dangerous" developer options to reset at the next boot (although I personally do not believe the said setting is dangerous).

I would be extremely grateful if someone could tell me how to change the code to make this particular setting's state permanent upon the next boot.

Here is the java file:
[DevelopmentSettings.java](https://github.com/AOSPA-legacy/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/kitkat/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java)

The string I am interested in is "DisableOverlays"

I am a total newbie when it comes to this sort of stuff so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is the file that is called upon when disable hw overlays is enabled (stated as DebugDisableHWC):
[SurfaceFlinger.cpp](https://github.com/AOSPA-legacy/android_frameworks_native/blob/kitkat/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger.cpp#L3077-Lundefined)

Comment: "Here is the java file" -- that file displays the Developer Options screen in the Settings app. It has nothing much to do with the *implementation* of the options themselves, including which ones are reset upon a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the response @CommonsWare. Like I said I'm new to this lol. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have necessary permissions to do that - android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml and your app must be signed with system key. If you have permissions - here is code:

```
private void writeDisableOverlays() {
        try {
            Method getService = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getMethod("getService", String.class);
            IBinder flinger = (IBinder) getService.invoke(null, "SurfaceFlinger");
            if (flinger != null) {
                Parcel data = Parcel.obtain();
                data.writeInterfaceToken("android.ui.ISurfaceComposer");
                data.writeInt(1);
                flinger.transact(1008, data, null, 0);
                data.recycle();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```